# What software do you recommend to manage TV Series?

Tags: software-recommendation

I need a software to manage Tv Series, i.e rename episodes ( using TvRage or other providers ) and flagging episodes as watched in order to know which episodes I have not watched yet.

Do you know something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option you can use is GCstar it covers the options you need. Another possibilty is Griffith but it is geared more towards small video store use films/renting.

[More Info about gcstar](http://www.gcstar.org/)

[More Info About griffith](http://www.griffith.cc/)

Both are avaliable in the Software Center.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend XBMC using the XBMC standalone package. We've got loads of TV series on our server, with the only right part of the filename being the "season-episode" labels (S01E09) and XBMC picks them up right away.
I could go on but that's the only part relevant to the conversation.

Comment: XBMC is now called KODI.  It also manages movies, music, and pictures, plus it does a ton more.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try [boxee](http://www.boxee.tv). It's quite a big program if you only use it for Series though...

Features:

- Mark Episode as viewed (automatically)
- Show data about Episodes (description, name of episode)
- Automativally scan for and classify episodes in specified folders (only work for some naming conventions, but it's possible to manually classify them)
- List episodes you didn't download but that are available online (so you can stream them)

However, it does not rename any files and its a media-center software, not a series manager (so you can view episodes directly in the program).

To rename your files you could use [krename](http://packages.ubuntu.com/krename). But krename is for general files, it does not get any info from tvrage or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You may try [wxSeasons](https://launchpad.net/wxseasons). This isn't a well-developed app, but it may do something good to you.

Comment: This seems an interesting project but is stalled in development ( last update was 34 weeks ago ) and in this current state it doesnt able to meet any of my needs :/